# Exception com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.disconnectnontransientconnectionexception while running through azure pipeline

Tags: java, database, jdbc, db2, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am getting below error while running through azure pipeline but working fine while running in eclipse. Please help me with the resolution.

> Error message -
> "com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.disconnectnontransientconnectionexception:
> [jcc][t4][2043][11550][4.16.53] Exception java.net.ConnectException:
> Error opening socket to server / on port 
> with message: Connection timed out (Connection timed out).

I tried with all the dependency and jar files for jdbc but still getting same exception.

Comment: Most likely a networking configuation problem, between your application and the Db2-server. This is not a software problem. Verify that the Db2-server hostname is accessible/pingable from your application, and verify that the specific port number is opened all the way between your app and the Db2-server.

Comment: Hi. How did you solve your issue?